# Slave's datanodes not starting in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, bigdata

I followed [this](http://javadev.org/docs/hadoop/centos/6/installation/multi-node-installation-on-centos-6-non-sucure-mode/) tutorial and tried to setup a multinode hadoop cluster on centOS. After doing all the configurations and running `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh`, this is what `jps` outputs:

```
Master
26121 ResourceManager
25964 SecondaryNameNode
25759 NameNode
25738 Jps

Slave 1
19082 Jps
17826 NodeManager

Slave 2
17857 Jps
16650 NodeManager
```

Data node is not started on slaves.

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with this setup?

Comment: update your post with datanode logs

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaReddy datanode logs are empty nothing special are there. can you please tell me where can I find real logs.

Comment: Please check in the Hadoop installation directory, or the HADOOP_HOME. There should be a logs folder. You can also check in dfs.datanode.data.dir directory, or in the /tmp directory. I would also suggest to stop all the services, and try start-all.sh. If some problem happens, this should report that it was not able to start datanode, and logs are here.... Also, most probably it seems your ssh communication might not be working.

Comment: The other option (for checking logs) might be to run the DataNode on foreground: `/bin/hdfs datanode`. You should consider setting those vars: `HADOOP_LOG_DIR=/var/log/hdfs HADOOP_LOGFILE=hdfs-datanode.log HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=INFO,RFA HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER=INFO,RFAS JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/java/installation`